# I'm not sure how to carry on after a person selects one question

Tags: replit

```
 System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("I knew something was up driving past that billboard.");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("Something didn’t feel right.");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(sName + " " + "Watch out there's a deer!!!");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("1) Turn to the left ");//Three options to choose from.
System.out.println("2) Turn to the right ");
System.out.println("3) Continue driving forward ");

int iAnswer = 0;// Need to put this above so it'll work.
iAnswer = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine()); // Finding when we're getting there
if (iAnswer == 1) {
  System.out.println("You skid to the left dramatically, and injure Keith badly.");
if (iAnswer == 2) {
  System.out.println("Skid to the right fast avoiding the deer and crash the car into a tree damaging" + " " + sName + ".");
if (iAnswer == 3){
  System.out.println("You hit the deer, and die of a fatal accident flipping the car and killing both your friends.");

    }
  }
}
```

For example if the person playing chooses 1 as the answer resulting in Keith being injured badly from the car crash I'd like to use this as a disadvantage later for the person playing. How'd I tell the PC to follow that specific path onward from that answer. And how'd I end the game if they chose question 3 resulting in all characters dying.

Comment: You've got an answer. You should either accept it, or explain the author why it doesn't solve your problem. Keep in mind that people are investing time helping you by writing answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean variable `keithInjured` at the beginning of the program, set it to true if the user enters 1, and check its value later in the program when it is relevant.

You can put the different execution path in methods, and call the right method in the if-statements.

Also note that you wrapped the last 2 if-statement (which check if the input was 2 or 3) into the first one. If the first if-statement's condition evaluates to false, the second two will not be checked because they are within the scope of the first one. Close the braces of an if-statement at the end of its code block.

```
boolean keithInjured = false;     
if (iAnswer == 1) {
          System.out.println("You skid to the left dramatically, and injure Keith badly.");
          keithInjured = true;
         path1();
}
if (iAnswer == 2) {
          System.out.println("Skid to the right fast avoiding the deer and crash the car into a tree damaging" + " " + sName + ".");
          path2();
}
if (iAnswer == 3){
          System.out.println("You hit the deer, and die of a fatal accident flipping the car and killing both your friends.");
          path3();
 }
//later in program
if (keithInjured) {
     //do something
}
```